# python subprocess.run via crontab

Tags: python, docker-compose, cron, subprocess

I wrote a python script that calls a `docker-compose exec` command via `subprocess.run`. The script works as intended when I run it manually from the terminal, however I didn't get it to work as a cronjob yet.

The subprocess part looks like this:
`subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output= True, text=True, cwd='/home/ubuntu/directory_of_the_script/')`

and the command itself is something like
`docker-compose exec container_name python3 folder/scripts/another_script.py -parameter`

I assume it has something to do with the paths, but all thevreading and googling I did recently didn't get me to fix the issue.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

I added `cwd='/home/ubuntu/directory_of_the_script/` to the `subprocess` hoping to fix the path issues.
Also `cd /path/to/script` in the cronjob didn't fix the thing

Comment: What does happen when the cron job runs?  Is this in your user crontab, or is it in a root crontab?

Comment: When the script runs as a crontab nothing happens. At least nothing I can see. 
It’s in the user crontab.

Comment: Redirect `stderr` and `stdout` of the python command in crontab to a file. Then you will be able to see the reason why it's failing.

Comment: Usually the reason is that you depend on environment variables that are set in one of your shell startup scripts. These scripts aren't run by cron.

Comment: OK, I got the redirecting of `stderr`and `stdout` to work. The respective line in crontab looks like this now: `* * * * * cd ~/folder && python3 test2.py >> ~/folder/logs/updater_logs/test2.log 2>&1` However the logfile does not contain any error messages, only a couple of print commands from the python-script. I also assume it has to do with the environment variables. Unfortunately this is where I get to the end of my expertise. I do not know how to find which variables are the ones to be set and how to set them.